# What is the difference between Hibernate OGM and Kundera

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, kundera, hibernate-ogm

I am evaluating what might be the best framework option between kundera and Hibernate OGM.
My Situation:
 Existing project uses hibernate ORM for contacting Mysql data store. Now i want to read/write to cassandra(2.1.9) data store in the same project.
I want to know the pros and cons of using kundera or Hibernate OGM.

Hibernate OGM road map states that "Getting the Cassandra mapping store data in natural Cassandra persistence patterns." will be available from 5.0. what am i actually missing if i don't have this feature and does kundera have this feature.

Comment: In the same way DataNucleus JPA/JDO have supported MongoDB since before either of your two considered solutions came into existence. It also supports Cassandra and other datastores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [`Kundera!`](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera)

**My reasons:**

> Why not Hibernate OGM?

- Hibernate OGM added support for Cassandra only in the recent release (4.2) and has many things not yet supported
- Hibernate OGM's support for Cassandra is in "tech preview" state at this moment
- Support for clustering is not yet supported
- No proper documentation yet

> Why Kundera?

- Kundera's support for Cassandra is pretty mature and has decent [`documentation`](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-Started-in-5-minutes)
- Easy to use (JPA compliant)
- Support for clustering and many other Cassandra specific features
- Supports [Polyglot Persistence](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Polyglot-Persistence) out-of-the-box
- Supports indexing of data on Elasticsearch for adhoc querying, usually not supported by a NoSQL datastore

References:

- [NoSQL benchmarking](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s13174-016-0052-x)
- [Kundera github](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera)
- [Blog by Gunnar Morling](http://in.relation.to/2015/05/20/cassandra-support-query-improvements-more-builtin-types-hibernate-ogm-420-cr-1-is-out/)

Comment: Hey, you really should make apparent that you [contribute](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/commits/trunk/src/kundera-cassandra?author=karthikprasad13) to the Kundera Cassandra support (disclaimer: I am contributing to Hibernate OGM). Yes, the Cassandra backend for Hibernate OGM is still under development, we work hard to make it more complete. Docs are [there](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-cassandra). Also it's JPA-based by nature of Hibernate, so that's no sole pro for Kundera.

Comment: @Gunnar I agree that you guys are working really hard to make HOGM more complete. Also, I only meant to say that Kundera is **also** JPA compliant and not otherwise. I really liked your blog btw.. :)

Comment: Hi, fast forward 20 months, we are now in May 2017.  What would be the pros and cons for Hibernate OGM and Kundera now?  Thanks!

Comment: @leeyuiwah IMHO you should explore both and check for yourself as to which fits your usecase. Advantages of Kundera over OGM are polyglot persistence and elasticsearch indexing.

Comment: @leeyuiwah check [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s13174-016-0052-x) benchmarking

Comment: Interesting benchmark. Especially chapter 7.2, highlighting how Kundera is having an unfair advantage because of a bug. Anyway, a lot more is wrong with using that document to make an absolutist decision, like not having enabled any of the performance tuning options 
 - which would be used in real world apps. Great comparison though, thanks!